# C++ : Starting a timer from a certain timestamp, and incrementing it

Tags: c++, opencv, timer

I am trying to write a program which will process a video file and will handle a timer along with it. Every video file has a `.txt` file next to it, including the time when the video was shot (like 13:43:21) in real time, I want my program to read this `.txt` file, and start a timer from that particular timestamp, and tick as it ticks in the video file.

So far I already can read the `.txt` file and I have the starting time stored in a `string` variable. Now, what I want to do is, to create a timer which will start off from the read string variable and tick as the video plays, so that in my program I synchronize with the time ticking in the video.

Edit: I am using OpenCV as library.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04  LTS

Comment: And what video playback library are you using?

Comment: OpenCV @JohnZwinck

Comment: Do you want a "tick" at every frame? And if so, what is the frame rate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the possible solution.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <ctime>
 #include <unistd.h>

 class VideoTimer {
 public:
     // Initializing offset time in ctor.
     VideoTimer(const std::string& t) {
         struct tm tm;
         strptime(t.c_str(), "%H:%M:%S", &tm);
         tm.tm_isdst = -1;
         offset = mktime(&tm);
     }
     // Start timer when video starts.
     void start() {
         begin = time(nullptr);
     }
     // Get video time syncronized with shot time.
     struct tm *getTime() {
         time_t current_time = offset + (time(nullptr) - begin);
         return localtime(&current_time);
     }   
 private:
     time_t offset;
     time_t begin;
 };  

 int main() {
     auto offset_time = "13:43:59";
     auto timer = VideoTimer(offset_time);
     timer.start();

     // Do some work.

     auto video_tm = timer.getTime();
     // You can play around with time now. 
     std::cout << video_tm->tm_hour << ":" << video_tm->tm_min << ":" << video_tm->tm_sec << "\n";

     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need RTC timer or just to keep video and text in sync?

I would suggest getting frame rate and converting all text timestamps into number of frames from beginning of video file.

Pseudocode:

```
static uint64_t startTime = (startHours * 60 + startMinutes) * 60 + startSeconds;
static float fps = 60.00;

uint64_t curFrameFromTimestamp(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
{
    return ((hours * 60 + minutes) * 60 + seconds - startTime) * fps;
}
```